# Image not showing on CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to show an image behind a text as a background image. I tried adding it to CSS but won't work, I added the image on the HTML file and it worked.

I tried to add the image on the HTML file and it worked, but won't work on the CSS

Here's the HTML code :

```
<main>
        <section class="fullpage" id="journey">Journey of Mine</section>
            
        <p>Copyright © Amadeus Gavriel Tataming. 2024</p>
    </main>
```

Here's the CSS code :

```
.fullpage {
    position: relative; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
    height: 100vh; 
    font-size: 2em; 
    color: #333;
}

.fullpage::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('humanoid-robot.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The image path is on the same directory as both my HTML and CSS file.

Is there anyone that can help me through this or tell me what I did wrong? It'd mean a lot as this is my first project on web development.

Comment: For me it works: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/oyb4w27q/ . 

Comment: Check if u have imported the css file properly 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
make sure to use similar if you are using external css

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thank you. Turns out I had a background-color on the html, body{} which overlaps the picture. But out of curiosity, is there a way to make the background color to appear at the very back so it doesn't overlap anything? Thank you!